# Predicate function for dotted pairs?

Tags: elisp

**Q:** is there a predicate function for dotted pairs?

In other words, is there a function that distinguishes between dotted pairs and 2-element proper lists:

```
(some-predicate-p '(a . b))             ; => t
(some-predicate-p '(a   b))             ; => nil
```

The broader context: I need to access the second element of a pair of values, and would like the function to "do the right thing" when it's fed either a dotted pair or a 2-element proper list:

```
(cdr  '(a . b))                           ; => b
(cadr '(a   b))                           ; => b
```

Since `cdr` and `cadr` cannot be dropped in interchangeably between proper and improper lists:

```
(cadr '(a . b))                           ; => error
(cdr  '(a   b))                           ; => (b)
```

Comment: `(and (cdr x) (atom (cdr x)))`  FWIW, this is a duplicate of [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11072056/729907), except that here you are testing only one cons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple test for a dotted pair (your question):

```el
(and (cdr x) (atom (cdr x)))
```

And here is a test for a dotted list (of any length):

```el
(let ((last  (last x))) (and (cdr last) (atom (cdr last))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Got it: helped along by @abo-abo's answer, the following predicate function detects dotted pairs:

```
(defun dotted-p (x)
  "Returns `t' if X is a dotted-pair."
  (not (consp (cdr x))))

(dotted-p '(a . b))                     ; => t
(dotted-p '(a   b))                     ; => nil
```

Comment: The only issue I could see here is that '(a . nil) be considered a dotted pair when really it just a 1 element proper list (equivilant to '(a)), If you wanted to account for this, and also for full type safety, you could use this is your function body `(and (consp x) (cdr x) (not (consp (cdr x))))`

Comment: @JordonBiondo: good point on the edge case.  I think, for my specific use, I'd want to leave it as is, but the more general case should probably work as you're suggesting.

Comment: I disagree.  `(cons a nil)` is by definition a dotted pair, even though it can also be regarded as a one-element list. But I would certainly include the `(consp x)` condition as suggested by @JordonBiondo.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't such a function to my knowledge, but you can use something like this:

```cl
(defun codr (x)
  (let ((y (cdr x)))
    (if (consp y)
        (car y)
      y)))
```

But it's better to just know what kind of data you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks, although this function return the same value (`b`) when used on either a dotted-pair or a proper list: `(codr '(a b))` => `b` and `(codr '(a . b))` => `b`.  Still, +1 because it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: And I agree that it's better to know the type of data to expect, but it's for end-user use and I'd like to allow people to use either version as their tastes dictate.